# how to use subquery in laravel eloquent selectRaw method?

Tags: laravel

So I have a table named chats which keeps every users messages and the table have id,user_id,message as columns

I want to get a result like this using laravel eloquent

| 19/12/2020 | 20/12/2020 |
| --- | --- |
| number of users who started a chat | 5 |
| number of messages | 25 |

my current eloquent query builder is

```
$data = Chat::groupBy('day')
    ->selectRaw("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM chats group by user_id ) as user_counts,count(messages), DATE(created_at) as day")
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply count them using below code:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

Chat::groupBy('day')
    ->count(DB::raw('DISTINCT user_id'))
    ->count('message')
```